# SELECT trouble with DIFFTIME

Tags: mysql, select, time, nested, datediff

I want to know the time difference between two dates. 
for example:

```
    SELECT TIMEDIFF('2012-12-19 22:00:00','2012-12-10 19:00:00');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF('2012-12-19 22:00:00','2012-12-10 19:00:00') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 219:00:00                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i want to extract the hours.

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR(SELECT TIMEDIFF('2012-12-19 22:00:00','2012-12-10 19:00:00'));
ERROR 1064 (42000):
```

Why doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2012-12-19 22:00:00','2012-12-10 19:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could resolve your problem:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('2012-12-19 22:00:00','2012-12-10 19:00:00'),'%H');
```